# Multipling a parameter in GSP grails view

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to multiply a parameter in a GSP view like this:

```
<g:set var="denom" value="${ denomination.denomination.toDouble() * .01) }"/>
```

Grails keep screaming "unexpected token" with the '*' but it's totally fine when I try to add!!

```
<g:set var="denom" value="${ denomination.denomination.toDouble() + .01) }"/>
```

am i missing something?

Comment: You have an extra `)` after the `.01`. That's the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore omg im an idiot, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually caused by an extra `)` after the `.01`. So your expression should be:

`<g:set var="denom" value="${ denomination.denomination.toDouble() * .01 }"/>`

Answer (score -1):

so the issue was an extra `)` and that I had to type a zero to the left of my decimal

```
<g:set var="denom" value="${ denomination.denomination.toDouble() * 0.01 }"/>
```